# Viewport not working with domain name

Tags: web, viewport

I am making a responsive website and as you know, it relies on the meta viewport tag to work properly. I got free hosting and a free domain name that points to the original. When you view the website with the domain name, the viewport doesn't work, but the original works fine.

This one works fine: goldies-goodies.byethost16.com
This one points to ^^^ but viewport is broken: goldiesgoodies.tk

Answer (score 0):

Theres no Viewport meta tag on goldiesgoodies.tk

```
<html>
<head>
<title>goldiesgoodies.tk</title>
<meta name="description" content="goldiesgoodies.tk">
<meta name="keywords" content="goldiesgoodies.tk">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: But I don't think I can really control what html is displayed by dot tk, can I?

Comment: I'm not familar with your Hosting setup, but if the Parent viewport is not correct its doens't matter what the child(frameset,iframe) viewport is set to